# my personal github.io page redirect wrong adress

Tags: github, github-pages

My personal rentonhead.github.io redirect hasancemilacar.me domain name (that's was my old domain but idk how is it do that?)  I'm wondering how is that possible and how can i solution this redirect problem?

redirect problem my github.io pages wrong domain name

Answer (score 0):

To update your website's settings, navigate to the repository's Settings menu and proceed to the pages options. Look for the Custom domain section within. Remove the old domain and redeploy the website. To verify if the changes have taken effect, open an incognito window in your browser, as regular browsing may cause cache-related issues.